# Can't use Javascript when using AJAX (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I want to use Swiper Javascript Api(http://www.idangero.us/) in Jquery Mobile..
But because Jquery Mobile uses ajax, my javascript doesn't work.. 
Example sources are like that.

1. index.html

   ```
   <head>
   <link href="./scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <script src="./scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="./scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./scripts/idangerous.swiper.css"/>
   <script src="./scripts/idangerous.swiper.2.4.1.js" defer="true"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
   <div data-role="page">
       <div data-role="header"></div>
       <div role="main" class="ui-content page_content"><a href="sub.html">go sub page</a></div>
       <div data-role="footer"></div>
   </div>
   </body>
   ```
2. sub.html

   ```
   </head>

   <body>
   <div data-role="page">
       <div data-role="header">
       </div>
       <div role="main">

       <!-- using swipe javascript source-->
   <script defer="true">
   $(document).on('pagecreate', function() {
     var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
       //Your options here:
       mode:'horizontal',
       loop: true
       //etc..
     });  
   })
       <div class="swiper-container">
           <div class="swiper-wrapper">
               <!--First Slide-->
               <div class="swiper-slide" style="background:white;">
                   <center><font color="black">1</font></center>
                   <center><font color="black">page1</font></center>

               </div>
               <!--Second Slide-->
               <div class="swiper-slide" style="background:white;">
                   <center><font color="black" >2</font></center>
                   <center><font color="black" >page2</font></center>

               </div>
               <!-- Third Slide-->
               <div class="swiper-slide" style="background:white;">
                   <center><font color="black">3</font></center>
                   <center><font color="black">page3</font></center>

               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div data-role="footer"></div>
   </div>
   </body>
   ```

I used Swiper api(javascript) at sub.html. But when I access index.html page and click sub link, sub page's Swiper api doesn't work. When I refresh that page, it work.. 
How can I view the Swiper api even I do not refresh it?

Comment: for _single page model_ JS libraries and code should be placed inside _page div_. Move swiper JS library and code inside _page div_ of sub.html.

Comment: @Omar I moved it. But it doesn't work..(http://mbtistudy.cafe24.com/index.html)

Comment: Dont use `.ready()` instead use `$(document).on("pagecreate",  function () { swipre code });`. `pageinit` is deprecated in jQM 1.4 and replaced with `pagecreate`.

Comment: @Omar When I test function alert('hello'), it works.. but when I try to execute upper my source(swiper).. there is an ajax loading and don't turn sub page.. (http://mbtistudy.cafe24.com/index.html) do you know why.?

Comment: try `pagecontainershow` instead of `pagecreate`.

Comment: it works with `pagecontainershow` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mH4YW/

Comment: @Omar 'pageshow' or 'pagecontainershow' goes well.. Thank you!!

Comment: `pageshow` is deprecated as of jQM 1.4. its' replacement is `pagecontainershow`, however, you cant bind this event to a specific page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Mobile uses AJAX to load in your new page. However, it strips out the head--as well as anything outside a container with `data-role="page"` (or `body` if not provided).

The solution is to move your script so it appears within the section of the page that jQuery Mobile injects into the page, so it doesn't get removed.

Then, if you want to execute javascript on $.ready(), you'll  need to bind to [jQuery Mobile's `onPageInit` event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/) like so:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", function( event ) {
    alert( "This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!" );
});
```

In the real world, I've noticed that `pageinit` sometimes doesn't solve the problem, so if all else fails, [try binding to `pagebeforeshow`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/) and see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the document.ready is only fired once - when your page has initially been loaded and DOM is ready. You can put your code directly into a  tag in the loaded sub.html. No need to use the $(document).ready event handler.